# configuring profile specific spring-cloud-consul properties

Tags: spring, properties, configuration, spring-cloud

I am using `spring-cloud-starter-consul-config'. For this I defined my properties in`bootstrap.yml`. But I need to use profile specific consul properties which is not working in`bootstrap.yml`.

Also I need to use custom property file instead of `bootstrap.yml` so that i can load this custom file using `@PropertySource`. Any idea?

```
@SpringBoogApplication
@EnableAutoconfiguration
public class myApplication {
}
```

bootstrap.yml

```
environments:
  dev:
      spring:
        cloud:
          consul:
            host: dev-consul
            port: 8500
```

Comment: cant you put those properties in application-{env}.yml files? So it loads them by profile passed to app?

Comment: Does bootstrap-dev.yml work? If not you can define multiple yaml docs in one file, look at the spring boot docs.

Answer (score 0):

Create second `application-{env}.yml` and `bootstrap-{env}.yml` files.

Then build jar and start `java -jar app.jar -Dspring.profiles.active={env}`